# Plink in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python to run plink.exe to do an SSH session.  I would like to read stdout and if it returns a '#' I would like to send send a command. Is this possible?  Below is what I have so far.

```
import subprocess
import sys   
con_string = "C:\\Windows\\plink.exe user@host -i C:\\Windows\\key.ppk -P port"
process = subprocess.Popen(con_string, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), ''):
    sys.stdout.write(i.decode('utf-8')
```

if I try the following it doesn't work.

```
for i in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), ''):
    if i == '#':
      process.stdin.write(r'command')

    sys.stdout.write(i.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Is Paramiko not an option?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not familiar with Paramiko.  Are there simple examples to achieve what I'm trying to do?